# Permission denied when pushing to GitHub repository with Personal Access Token

Tags: git, github, push, personal-access-token

After first git push origin master request i got

> remote: Permission to rabiul7772/Forkify_Project.git denied to nahidhasan830.
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rabiul7772/Forkify_Project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403   this error.

Then i tried to push with Personal Access Token and got the following error

> remote: Permission to rabiul7772/Forkify_Project.git denied to rabiul7772.
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rabiul7772/Forkify_Project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Use SSH, not https.

Comment: 403 is "unauthorized": in both cases you've provided a valid set of credentials, but those accounts do not have permission to do what you've requested. Check that both accounts are able to write to that repo, and that you aren't trying to push to a protected branch.